# Creating single squared tile fishnet buffer based off shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, vector-grid

I'm interested in creating a fishnet buffer around a current grid I have. The fishnet buffer I'm interested in making needs to be exactly the same cell size and extend just one grid cell around the AOI.

How can I create such a result using QGIS?

The grids are square

I've provided an example of what I would like to the result to look like.

[image]

Comment: Are they squares?

Comment: Yes, the grids are squares.

Comment: Convert to grid of the same cell size. Expand by one, create fishnet. Alternatively convert expanded to points, to raster, to polygon.

Comment: @PolyGeo, if I were to ask a different question with the same verbiage but   request a response in ArcGIS is that okay as well?

Comment: @FelixIP I just updated the question for using QGIS in the workflow. Would your response still apply? Which specific tools?

Comment: Yes - the only difference between two such questions is likely to be what you have tried with the particular software being asked about in that question. The preamble is fine to stay the same.

Comment: It is a bit tricky though, one need to know how to change environment extents accordingly.